# Problem with string

Tags: ruby, string, integer, fixnum

I'm doing a script in Ruby to read some pack files and see what they contain.
I wrote this very simple script yesterday that gives me a headache:

```
arch = File.new(*file_name*, "r")
z = arch.sysread(1).unpack('H*')
puts z
content = arch.sysread(32)
```

The variable `z` above has a value of 10.  If I pass this into `sysread` I get an error, yet if I define a variable `x` and assign it a value of ten and pass that in, it runs OK.

Why can't I pass `z` to `sysread`?

Comment: Use `p z` rather than `puts z` probably `z` isn't really `10`. Also, you should say what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file as binary, with `"rb"` instead of `"r"`, and you said that it gives a error, which error?

Anyway, the `unpack` function returns a `Array`, in this case, with a hexadecimal number as a string. You probably want to do this: `content = arch.read(z.first.to_i(16))`.

This code makes more sense (if you are trying to do what I think):

```
arch = File.open("filename", "rb") # open the file as binary
z = arch.read(1).bytes.first       # get the first byte as a integer
content = arch.read(z)             # read the next z bytes
```

Comment: i want to extract some text from file. In the file put the long of the text, and i need this number.

Comment: @Sergio, put in your question a sample of the file and the input that you want. Is the file binary? There's more contents or just this text that you want? (you can, maybe, read the entire file) Or you want to read a part of a binary file that is prefixed if itself size? How is this size saved? Give more informations!

Comment: i need to read the file in hex because i need the value in this format. The file extension is *.dat, no text. I put a sample of the header file.

                        MTAF¸0                         ‹–‹“š ˜’Ñ’‹žÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿHEAD°             @      +-       +-

Comment: I cant sent the file because it size is 700MB

Comment: Ok, i changed the code and the script runs great, Thank you!